# Force youtube embed to start in 720p

Tags: html, youtube, embed

There are a few methods suggested for doing this online, but none of them seem to work.

For example:

http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2008/11/youtube-in-720p-hd-viewin.html

That article is about making it start in 720p, but it doesn't even work on their own video.

Does anyone here know how to do it?

Comment: Well, it's for my website and there wasn't any more appropriate place to ask that I could think of. I assumed I had the highest chances of recieving an answer here.

Comment: t1gor's answer was the same as TrySpace's.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

*(This answer was updated, as the previous method using `vq` isn't recognized anymore.)*

Specifying the height of the video will change the quality accordingly.
example for html 5;

```
<iframe style='width:100%; height:800px;' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx'></iframe>
```

If you don't want to hardcode the width and height you can add a class to the iframe for css media queries.

Tested on a working server + passes the w3.org nuhtml validator.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. But it seems like you don't even need the hd, &vq=hd1080 worked for me

Comment: This works although it is not documented in the youtube player doc. Btw, the other suggestion, &hd=1, is deprecated and doesn’t work with latest iframe embed code.

Comment: This works as well when viewing videos stored in Google Drive - you can even add the ?vq=hd720 or ?vq=hd1080 to the URL of a folder that you have shared, and all the videos in there will open in HD by default.

Comment: A default embed may not have anything in the query string, so don't forget to add a handy dandy ``?`` to your source url. E.g: ``<iframe width="324" height="182" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/V1234580?vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>``

Comment: I can't get this to work when embedding in a forum post. For example here: http://www.rpgmakervxace.net/topic/24781-datsville-rpg-currently-v050/#entry180834

Comment: Make sure that the iframe is of suitable size (and not e.g. `display:none`) when it is first loaded into the DOM or the video can play in lower quality for the first few seconds.

Answer (score 24):

You can do this by adding a parameter `&hd=1` to the video URL. That forces the video to start in the highest resolution available for the video. However you cannot specifically set it to 720p, because not every video has that hd ish.

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID&hd=1

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html

UPDATE: as of 2014, hd is deprecated
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#Deprecated_Parameters

Comment: Its the same thing. If your embedding add the `&hd=1` it starts up in the highest possible resolution.

Comment: No, it does work on links. like this: http://www.youtube.com/v/l9Cg5rlSe28&hd=1 but it doesn't work on object embeds. I'll try an iframe embed and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work like this: `<iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/l9Cg5rlSe28&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Answer (score 10):

Youtube doesn't support playback quality anymore

[image: Youtube doesn't support playback quality anymore]

Comment: this info can also be found here
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 8):

This is an embed example of video played in HD 1080.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://youtube.com/v/IplDUxTQxsE&vq=hd1080" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
```

Let's break apart the code:`http://youtube.com/v/` `video_id` `&vq=hd1080`

Video id for that video: IplDUxTQxsE you will see this type of random code in the link of every YouTube video.

So far so good, this trick works for playing full HD videos directly on webpages!

You can change the quality to 720 too. `&vq=hd720`

Answer (score 7):

2021 here is my answer that works.

```
https://youtube.com/embed/ZkTzXrczk5M?vq=hd720p;feature=oembed&amp;controls=0&amp;hd=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0
```

The secret is in placing a "p" e.g. ?vq=hd720p not ?vq=hd720,  after your desired resolution on the of the src.

Comment: This got me there, thank you so much!  Here is what I had to use (the iframe width and height had to be set) <iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxx?vq=hd720p;hd=1" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Note that the query string ampersand syntax for parameters after the first one eg https://www.youtube.com/embed/NfxpqYjLrDQ?si=FaVpQR3TiXRSy6RK&vq=hd720p

Answer (score 6):

I've managed to get this working by the following fix:

```
//www.youtube.com/embed/_YOUR_VIDEO_CODE_/?vq=hd720
```

You video should have the hd720 resolution to do so.

I was using the embedding via iframe, BTW. Hope someone will find this helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The first example below does not work for me, but the second one does (in Chrome).

```
<iframe width="720" height="405" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/GX_c566xYcQ?rel=0&vq=hd1080" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
<iframe width="720" height="405" src="//youtube.com/v/IplDUxTQxsE?rel=0&vq=hd1080" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
```

I believe the first one uses the new HTML5 youtube player whereas the bottom one (which works) uses the older flash player.  However, the second one doesn't seem to load correctly in Safari/Firefox etc so probably not usable.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above solutions seem to work if the width/height is less than the line resolution of quality  you select.
For example, the following doesn't work for me in Chrome:

```
<iframe width="720" height="480" src="//youtube.com/embed/hUezoHa1ZF4?autoplay=true&rel=0&vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to show the high quality video, but *not* use up 1280 x 720 pixels on the webpage.

When I go to youtube itself, playing 720p video in a 720x480 window looks better than 480p at the same size. I want to play 720p in a 720x480 window (downsampled better quality). There is no good solution yet afaik.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're still wondering how to do it, then add: &feature=youtu.be&hd=1
Actually now I checked, this works only when you're sending the URL to someone else, not on embed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it works 100%  _your_videocode?rel=0&vq=hd1080"