# Embed youtube player at 720p

Tags: youtube, embed

I have a youtube video featuring screen recording that really benefits from being in HD, unfortunately  it appears to be no longer possible to force hd at embed sizes smaller than 1280px x 720px. I have tried adding &hd=1 to the url param, but it no longer works.

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIBI1jPZQ55?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&hd=1&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

is there anyway around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force youtube embed to start in 720p](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582336/force-youtube-embed-to-start-in-720p)

Answer (score 0):

Add &vq=hd1080 instead of &hd=1

Please check for previously answered questions on the same subject in the future, cheers.