# Force youtube player to play in hd720 quality

Tags: android, webview, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to play youtube video on my android app using Youtube Player API for Android but the problem is getting that the video quality of the video is not so good and there is not an option for force setting it to HD. So I tried to play video using Youtube Iframe API in android Webview but also there I'm facing the same problem with video quality.

Iframe Code :

```
<div class="videowrapper">
     <iframe id=\"player\" width=\"720\" height=\"1280\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"encrypted-media\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/uFExenM7-dY?vq=hd720&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;controls=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0\"></iframe>\n"
</div>

.videowrapper {
     float: none;
     clear: both;
     background:#eeeeee;
     width: 100%;
}
.videowrapper iframe {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

How to make Youtube video to always play in HD quality?

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching the `vq=VIDEO_QUALITY` to a youtube video url like

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzliFQ-36kg&vq=720
```

To make this work using embed, follow the answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21947442/6143482).

```
<object width="1280" height="720"><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0&amp;vq=hd720"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
```

Testing on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbc23g7q/1/).

Don't forget to change `VIDEO_ID` to valid one when testing this.

Comment: I have already added that parameter and still video not playing in HD quality.

Comment: why are you embedding two different youtube video in the embedded frame?

Comment: How will I control this object frame from youtube java API script like play, pause ..?

Comment: Do some reading [Youtube IFRAME API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Comment: No, what I'm asking is how should I get Iframe from the above object defined?

Comment: Is this supported in android Webview?
Becuase I'm using youtube player on android Webview.