# Embed YouTube video to play HD720 by default

Tags: html

Want to embed YouTube and set its default to HD 720, not auto.

```
<iframe width="241" height="136"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NMG0CMkuUnA?version=3&vq=hd720" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Somehow this does not work.
How to make the YouTube to play at HD720 by default, not auto.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582336/force-youtube-embed-to-start-in-720p

Comment: It seems that `vq` doesn't work anymore, maybe is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe width="324" height="182" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YOURVIDEOCODE?vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

the `vq=hd720` part is what you need to add.

but beware this only works with `4:3` and `16:9` aspect ratio.

To read more about it here is a link to google developers website on the topic https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference