# How to force youtube to load videos in HD when player is smaller than 1280x720?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

My youtube space for video is 740x446 for desktops.
Client wants to force youtube to load 720p video there because it looks better.

Is it possible to do it and how?

What I tried:
[Force youtube embed to start in 720p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582336/force-youtube-embed-to-start-in-720p) (outdated / doesn't work)
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality

developers.google link says that you can only suggest not force quality.
In that case, does it even make sense to suggest it? Is this suggestion ever going to be listened to?

I'd prefer to avoid using javascript if not necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force youtube embed to start in 720p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582336/force-youtube-embed-to-start-in-720p)

Comment: how can it look better than 480p?

Comment: @hsz that question is linked in the question

Comment: @LucaKiebel - with images, and videos, every scale up reduces quality. Scaling down is ok.