# Youtube iframe api auto play not working for chrome and video resolution set not working for all browser

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

```js
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
                tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
                var player;
                function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                    player = new YT.Player('youtube-vid', { 
                    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                    });
                }
                function onPlayerReady(event) {
                   event.target.playVideo(); 
                    event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080'); 
                }
                function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
                    if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                        player.playVideo(); 
                      }
                      
                }
</script>
```

> Please help me out to set youtube quality hd1080 and auto play on page
>   load I used the above code but it not working for me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582336

Answer (score 7):

**Chrome's autoplay policies changed in April of 2018** 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Google Chrome will not allow autoplay video. If you want to auto play then you have to mute video. As per policy guidelines.

FireFox browser
[image]
Google Chrome
[image]

```js
// This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

//    This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

//  The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.setPlaybackRate(2);
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Had to go like this to get start in Chrome:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) { 
  player.mute(); // have to in order to allow auto start in chrome! 
  player.seekTo(20, true); 
}
```