Maximize quality in a YouTube video using the API in Javascript
I'm doing a small project for a multicam website and I would like to know if using the YouTube API I can make the video appear in a predefined way with the highest possible quality. The program is very simple, I added the javascript code to see if someone who has worked with it or understands the subject can help me.
This is the code:
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/FTw5xuq2swo?si=FEoxfsIQhmr4cu",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rg7kw-KLDL8?si=pABas8BsqLuQnP",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/uH1W01t_lGc?si=chERPVJdUGf-Q",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mu-dvOOnaOw?si=nckTPbwRLvVVqF",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/c212qMUTnEs?si=_bkJR78x2cX9FX",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/uH1W01t_lGc?si=4UxhxVaVJpspE1_",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/RsIG9WF-B4s?si=ETIOowVKEUaDBX",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/qw3uaLRrYNY?si=0epReb6olWaEP9",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/OWCh3wmKtak?si=t3fjj5cE90Gv",
];

function createIframes(videoUrls) {
    const videoGrid = document.getElementById('videoGrid');
    videoUrls.forEach((url, index) => {
        const iframeContainer = document.createElement('div');
        iframeContainer.id = 'player' + index;
        iframeContainer.className = 'grid-item';
        videoGrid.appendChild(iframeContainer);
    });
}

createIframes(videoUrls);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    videoUrls.forEach((url, index) => {
        new YT.Player('player' + index, {
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            videoId: extractVideoID(url),
            playerVars: {
                'autoplay': 1,
                'mute': 1
            }
        });
    });
}

function extractVideoID(url) {
    const urlObj = new URL(url);
    return urlObj.searchParams.get('v') || urlObj.pathname.split('/').pop();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const videoGrid = document.getElementById('videoGrid');

    const numVideos = videoUrls.length;
    const numCols = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(numVideos));
    const numRows = Math.ceil(numVideos / numCols);

    videoGrid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${numCols}, 1fr)`;
    videoGrid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${numRows}, 1fr)`;
});```


It doesn't look like you can preset which quality to use https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

The quality available is determined by the connection speed and screen size of the client. There's nothing you can do in the YT API to specify the desired quality

Used to be possible, but isn't any more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582336/force-youtube-embed-to-start-in-720p

Unfortunately, as you already noticed, this feature is not in YouTube's iFrame or Embed API.
The best possible way to get maximized quality from YouTube is to create a backend server that is able to serve streams and fetch video's data and use the server to get highest stream quality.
The Youyubei.js module is made for this; I use it a lot, and it gives you access to the same YouTube APIs that YouTube itself uses. Take a look yourself; browser version is supported too, if i'm not wrong.
But remember, video and audio are separated streams, so you should consider merging those streams together or using different method to stream both of them at once. But if you don't really need the extra high quality, remuxed stream (usually has around 480p, has both audio and video in one stream) could be used too.
